# On delete set null creating table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am to create a table named patientmedicinecategory . as given below:-

```
 CREATE TABLE patientmedicinecategory
 (
 pmc         int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 patient_id  int(11) NOT NULL,
 med_id      int(3) NOT NULL,
 cat_id      int(3) NOT NULL,
 testname    varchar(100) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY(pmc),
 UNIQUE KEY(patient_id, med_id,cat_id,testname),
 FOREIGN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE    
 CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(med_id) REFERENCES medicine(med_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES category(cat_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
 )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

my patient table is :-

```
  CREATE TABLE patient
  (
  patient_id    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  salutation    ENUM('Mr.','Mrs.','Miss.','Dr.') NOT NULL,
  name      varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  email_id  varchar(100),
  year      int(4) NOT NULL,
  month     int(3),
  day       int(3),
  sex       ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL,
  contactno         varchar(50),    

  PRIMARY KEY(patient_id)
  )ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

medicine table is :-

```
  CREATE TABLE medicine
  (
  med_id  int(3) NOT NULL,
  name    varchar(40) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (med_id)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

category table is :-

```
  CREATE TABLE category
  (
  cat_id    int(3) NOT NULL,
  name      varchar(20) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But when i try to create this it give the error:-

```
   ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'nutech3.patientmedicinecategory' (errno: 150)
```

I have tried a lot but could not success . please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Log in as `root` and run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.

Comment: engine=innodb is working properly. it is not the problm

Comment: I think here comes the solution you are looking for 

[stackoverflow same question link ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045279/error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: It seems you didn't run the command but it's probably my fault because I forgot to explain its purpose. `150` is a foreign key error. The only way to see the exact error message is the aforementioned command.

Answer (score 9):

If you log in as root and run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` you'll see that the exact error message is this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130405 11:55:42 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/patientmedicinecategory:
FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES category(cat_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
 )ENGINE=InnoDB:
You have defined a SET NULL condition though some of the
columns are defined as NOT NULL.
```

This is the offending line:

```
FOREIGN KEY(cat_id) REFERENCES category(cat_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
```

MySQL cannot make `patientmedicinecategory.cat_id` NULL because its defined this way:

```
cat_id      int(3) NOT NULL,
```

Your options are either:

- Allow `cat_id` to be `NULL`
- Set a different `ON DELETE` condition

Comment: +1 I haven't known the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command before. Finally some helpful info about the evil InnoDB errors.