# Mysql: using two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL workbench to design a database. Server is mysql 5.5.6

I've defined a few foreign keys linking the "candidates" table to the "countries" table. I get this error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'customer.candidats' (errno: 150)
```

The thing is: i'm referencing twice the countries table: once for the "nationality" column, once for the user address's country of origin. Is that allowed? Is this the right way to do it?

Here is the generated code that seems to trigger the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer`.`candidats` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `prenom` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `qualite` ENUM('0001','0002') NULL COMMENT '0001 = Madame\n0002 = Monsieur',
  `sexe` SET('1','2') NULL COMMENT '1 = Femme\n2 = Homme',
  `date_de_naissance` DATE NULL,
  `Nationalite` INT NOT NULL,
  `selor_bilinguisme` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `rue` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  `numero` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `pays` INT NOT NULL,
  `region` INT NOT NULL,
  `localité` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `code_postal` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(241) NULL,
  `tel_domicile` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `tel_bureau` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `tel_mobile` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `tel_prefere` ENUM('01','02','03') NULL DEFAULT '03',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_candidats_pays_idx` (`Nationalite` ASC, `pays` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_candidats_régions1_idx` (`region` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_candidats_pays`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Nationalite` , `pays`)
    REFERENCES `customer`.`pays` (`id` , `id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_candidats_régions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`region`)
    REFERENCES `customer`.`régions` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The "pays" table ("countries" in French)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer`.`pays` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom_fr` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nom_nl` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nationalite_fr` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `nationalite_nl` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045279/error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-errno-150

Comment: This is weird: REFERENCES `brujobs`.`pays` **(`id` , `id`)**. How does the `pays`table look like?

Comment: I've updated my Question with the table statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema generator doesn't work correctly.

It should generate:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_candidats_pays`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pays`)
    REFERENCES `customer`.`pays` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_candidats_Nationalite`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Nationalite`)
    REFERENCES `customer`.`pays` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

To your other question: This type of referencing seems strange when you see it the first time, but it's quite normal and I think there is no other way of constructing this type of relationship.

Comment: but i want to link 2 columns of the 'candidats' table; one for the country name, the other for the nationality term. Not possible?

Comment: And your INDEX `fk_candidats_pays_idx` probably won't do what you want, except you have many queries like `where pays=N and Nationalite=M`