# cant create a MySql table

Tags: mysql

I have created this table

```
CREATE TABLE `Overview` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ops` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `beneficiary_Institution` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `public_Expenditure_Budget` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payments` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completition_percent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finish` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_projects` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `public_aid` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operational_programme_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operational_programme` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_ops` text,
  `map_coordinates` varchar(15000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ops`,`date`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and i try to create a table that has a foreign key with that

```
CREATE TABLE `Proposal_Body` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ops` VARCHAR(11) NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `representative` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Proposal_Body_1_idx` (`ops` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Proposal_Body_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ops`)
    REFERENCES `espanew`.`Overview` (`ops`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This and any other attempt i tried gives me this error

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table
>   'Espa_Projects_Eng.Proposal_Body' (errno: 150)

I know that this is a foreign key problem, but i cant see the reason. This code is a comming from the mysql client, where i did the creation using the ui, didnt type the commands by hand, so it should work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825362/mysql-error-150-foreign-keys

Comment: Have you checked  that your first table i.e. "Overview" is present in DB?

Comment: You can refer points given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045279/error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-errno-150). This might help you.

Comment: I was so sure that i can have one foreign key pointing to a PK of a composite keys! using the same mysql, on my machine, it did work some time ago. dont know if i changed something since then, but now it appears that it doesnt allow me to do such a connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the documentation:

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the correct column names and types, and it must have indexes on
>   the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied,
>   MySQL returns Error 1005 and refers to Error 150 in the error message,
>   which means that a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.
>   Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails due to Error 150, this means that a
>   foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered
>   table.

As you can see your first table has this primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ops`,`date`)
```

but in the second table the foreign key is:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`ops`)
```

You have to correct this to make it work.

Comment: are you implying that i cant have a foreign key point to one of the PK of the refereed table? i have never heard that before

Comment: @SkarosIlias Of course, since in your Primary Key are involved more than one fields the Foreign Key has to match.

Answer (score 1):

Your Primary key is a composite key

> PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ops`,`date`)

And your foreign key is consist of only single column i.e.

> FOREIGN KEY (`ops`)

Foreign keys have to match the primary/unique key they reference column for column. To remove this error either you need to add `id` and `date` to the **Proposal_Body** table or your first table **Overview** primary key is wrong and should just be (`id`).